# Checkbox stays checked when clicking on it in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a dropdown list containing checkeboxes :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu columnsFilterDropDownMenu" id="columnsListDropDown">
   <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Type" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked="">&nbsp;Type</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="Release" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" checked="">&nbsp;Release</a></li>
</ul>
```

When i click on an entry in my dropdown, I wants to hide the dedicated columns into a table. I works fine when i clicked on the label, but when i click on the checkbox, the checkbox stays in the same state.

```
$('#columnsListDropDown a').on('click', function( event ) {
    var input = $(this).find("input");
    var columnName = $.trim($(this).text());
    if (event.target.localName === "input") {
    // Case where user has clicked on the input
        if ($(input).is(':checked')) {
            $("#myTable").find("[data-column='"+columnName+"']").show()
        } else {
            $("#myTable").find("[data-column='"+columnName+"']").hide()
        }
    } else {
    // Case where the user has clicked on the label, or in li element
        if ($(input).is(':checked')) {
            $("#myTable").find("[data-column='"+columnName+"']").hide()
            $(input).prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $("#myTable").find("[data-column='"+columnName+"']").show()
            $(input).prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The problem is because you cannot wrap a form input in an `<a>` element. The `a` will intercept the click event

Comment: wrap in label instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you cannot wrap a form input in an `<a>` element. The `a` will intercept the click event.

To fix this you can instead wrap the inputs in a `label`. You can also massively simplify your code by using the `value` of the checkbox to hold the column name, and also `toggle()` with the `checked` state of the checkbox. You can then also hook to the `change` event on the checkboxes directly as the `<a>` will not be interfering with the click event. Try this:

```js
$('#columnsListDropDown :checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $("#myTable").find("[data-column='" + this.value + "']").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu columnsFilterDropDownMenu" id="columnsListDropDown">
  <li>
    <label class="small" data-value="Type">
      <input type="checkbox" checked="" value="Type">
      Type
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="small" data-value="Release">
      <input type="checkbox" checked="" value="Release">
      Release
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td data-column="Type">Type</td>
    <td data-column="Release">Release</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I works very fine ! Thanks. There is yet another problem: when i click on the label, my dropdown is closed whereas it should stays opened to be able to check or uncheck other checkboxes

Comment: It's hard to say why that is with the code you've shown, but try calling `stopPropagation()` on the event passed to the handler

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question about that, making sure to include details of the dropdown library that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Use event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault to disable  events

```
$('#columnsListDropDown a').on('click', function( event ) {

    var input = $(this).find("input");
    var columnName = $.trim($(this).text());
    if (event.target.localName === "input") {
    // Case where user has clicked on the input
        if ($(input).is(':checked')) {
            $("#myTable").find("[data-column='"+columnName+"']").show()
        } else {
            $("#myTable").find("[data-column='"+columnName+"']").hide()
        }
    } else {
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();
    // Case where the user has clicked on the label, or in li element
        if ($(input).is(':checked')) {
            $("#myTable").find("[data-column='"+columnName+"']").hide()
            $(input).prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $("#myTable").find("[data-column='"+columnName+"']").show()
            $(input).prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

`